# Initialization of embedding space value for VQ-VAE

Tags: machine-learning, encoding-scheme, research

I am trying to study a research paper about VQ-VAE: [Neural Discrete Representation Learning](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/7a98af17e63a0ac09ce2e96d03992fbc-Paper.pdf), Aaron van den Oord, Oriol Vinyals, Koray Kavukcuoglu, NeurIPS 2017.

I have difficulty to understand the value of embedding vectors $e_j$ in this part (page 3 from the research paper):

> The posterior categorical distribution $q(z|x)$ probabilities are defined as one-hot as follows:
>
> $q(z=k|x)=\begin{cases}1, & \text{for k = }argmin_j ||z_e(x) - e_j||_2\\
> 0, & \text{otherwise} \\
> \end{cases}$

Here we define latent embedding space $e\in R^{K×D}$ and there are K embedding vectors $e_i \in R^D$.

My question is how to initialize latent embedding space and its value. Is it random initialization? Because we need to subtract our $z_e(x)$ with $e_j$ so embedding space $e$ must have some value.

Comment: Have you looked at the code of any VQ-VAE implementations?

Answer (score 0):

In initializing codebook embeddings, a common practice is to employ random initialization due to its simplicity and effectiveness in various contexts. A widely adopted method among practitioners is to sample values uniformly from a specified range. Specifically, the range is typically chosen to be between $-1/K$​ and $1/K$​, where K represents the total number of embeddings in the codebook.

[Here is an example](https://nbviewer.org/github/zalandoresearch/pytorch-vq-vae/blob/master/vq-vae.ipynb) of an implementation using this initialization: